# Reading binary file. Translate matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, binaryfiles, translate

I'm going to translate the working matlab code for reading the binary file to python code. Is there an equivalent for

```matlab
% open the file for reading
fid=fopen (filename,'rb','ieee-le');
% first read the signature
tmp=fread(fid,2,'char');
% read sizes
rows=fread(fid,1,'ushort');
cols=fread(fid,1,'ushort');
```

Comment: The more or less equivalent is https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html You just have to get the corresponding dtypes: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to do that, specifically the `unpack` function which accepts a buffer, but you'll have to read the required size from the input using `struct.calcsize`

```py
import struct
endian = "<"  # little endian
with open(filename,'rb') as f:
    tmp = struct.unpack(f"{endian}cc",f.read(struct.calcsize("cc")))
    tmp_int = [int.from_bytes(x,byteorder="little") for x in tmp]
    rows = struct.unpack(f"{endian}H",f.read(struct.calcsize("H")))[0]
    cols = struct.unpack(f"{endian}H",f.read(struct.calcsize("H")))[0]
```

you might want to use the [struct.Struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.Struct) class for reading the rest of the data in chunks, as it is going to be faster than decoding numbers one at a time.
ie:

```py
data = []
reader = struct.Struct(endian + "i"*cols)  # i for integer
row_size = reader.size
for row_number in range(rows):
    row = reader.unpack(f.read(row_size))
    data.append(row)
```

Edit: corrected the answer, and added an example for larger chuncks.

Edit2: okay, more improvement, assuming we are reading 1 GB file of shorts, storing it as python int makes no sense and will most likely give an out of memory error (or system will freeze), the proper way to do it is using [numpy](https://numpy.org/)

```py
import numpy as np
data = np.fromfile(f,dtype=endian+'H').reshape(cols,rows)  # ushorts
```

this way it'll have the same space in memory as it did on disk.

Comment: It shows me an error: tmp = unpack_from(f"{endian}c",f)[0]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'

Comment: @SerTet , i corrected the answer, sorry for that.

Comment: e.g. in Matlab `tmp = [1;0]`, your python code return me `tmp = b'\x01'`

Comment: @SerTet i didn't see the `2` in the matlab code, i just added it in, can you understand the above code ? or are you just copy-pasting ? the above code is just an example, you should read the documentation if you intend on getting much further from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I'm trying to understand the logic. Now python code returns for `tmp` `(b'\x01', b'\x00')`.

Comment: that is the correct representation of a character, i am assuming you want them as integers to use somewhere ? python is a strongly dynamically typed unlike matlab that is weakly typed, so i added `tmp_int` variable for the `integer representation of them` which is actually not char.

Comment: `tmp_int = [int(x) for x in tmp]` not worked for me. Following works `tmp_int = [int.from_bytes(x,'little') for x in tmp]`. But I not completely understood what is `byteorder="little"` and `byteorder="big"` here.

Comment: they refer to the system [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), since you are reading a char, the endianness is not really important, but for a short, it determines the order of the bytes, ie: on a little endian the first 8 bits are the most significant, while on a big endian the first 8 bits are the least significant, because hardware manufacturers couldn't agree on which should go first, so just read it the same way you wrote it, ie: `le` stands for little endian.